# How to install Wildcard TDM410P to my Debian?

Tags: debian, asterisk

I want to install a WCTDM/0 "Wildcard TDM410P in my Debian 7 for I use in my Asterisk, but I can't it. And it appear `DAHDI_SPANCONFIG failed on span 1: Invalid argument (22)`. I have to configure my `/etc/dahdi/system.conf` and my `/etc/dahdi/system.conf`

See my system.conf

```
       # Autogenerated by /usr/sbin/dahdi_genconf on Tue May 19 15:29:13 2015
# If you edit this file and execute /usr/sbin/dahdi_genconf again,
# your manual changes will be LOST.
# Dahdi Configuration File
#
# This file is parsed by the Dahdi Configurator, dahdi_cfg
#
# Span 1: WCTDM/0 "Wildcard TDM410P" (MASTER)
span = 1,1,0,ccs,hdb3,crc4
bchan = 1-15
dchan =16
fxsks=17-20
echocanceller=mg2,17-20
# channel 2, WCTDM/0/1, no module.
# channel 3, WCTDM/0/2, no module.
# channel 4, WCTDM/0/3, no module.

# Global data

loadzone        = br,us
```

When I use `dahdi_scan` it returns

```
  [1]
  active=yes
  alarms=OK
  description=Wildcard TDM410P
  name=WCTDM/0
  manufacturer=Digium
  devicetype=Wildcard TDM410P
  location=PCI Bus 05 Slot 05
  basechan=1
  totchans=4
  irq=0
  type=analog
  port=1,FXO
  port=2,none
  port=3,none
  port=4,none
```

And when I use `dahdi_cfg -vvvvvv`

```
      DAHDI Tools Version - 2.10.1

  DAHDI Version: 2.10.1
  Echo Canceller(s): MG2
  Configuration
  ======================

  SPAN 1: CCS/HDB3 Build-out: 0 db (CSU)/0-133 feet (DSX-1)

  Channel map:

  Channel 01: Clear channel (Default) (Echo Canceler: none) (Slaves: 01)
  Channel 02: Clear channel (Default) (Echo Canceler: none) (Slaves: 02)
  Channel 03: Clear channel (Default) (Echo Canceler: none) (Slaves: 03)
  Channel 04: Clear channel (Default) (Echo Canceler: none) (Slaves: 04)
  Channel 05: Clear channel (Default) (Echo Canceler: none) (Slaves: 05)
  Channel 06: Clear channel (Default) (Echo Canceler: none) (Slaves: 06)
   07: Clear channel (Default) (Echo Canceler: none) (Slaves: 07)
  Channel 08: Clear channel (Default) (Echo Canceler: none) (Slaves: 08)
  Channel 09: Clear channel (Default) (Echo Canceler: none) (Slaves: 09)
  Channel 10: Clear channel (Default) (Echo Canceler: none) (Slaves: 10)
  Channel 11: Clear channel (Default) (Echo Canceler: none) (Slaves: 11)
  Channel 12: Clear channel (Default) (Echo Canceler: none) (Slaves: 12)
  Channel 13: Clear channel (Default) (Echo Canceler: none) (Slaves: 13)
  Channel 14: Clear channel (Default) (Echo Canceler: none) (Slaves: 14)
  Channel 15: Clear channel (Default) (Echo Canceler: none) (Slaves: 15)
  Channel 16: D-channel (Default) (Echo Canceler: none) (Slaves: 16)
  Channel 17: FXS Kewlstart (Default) (Echo Canceler: mg2) (Slaves: 17)
  Channel 18: FXS Kewlstart (Default) (Echo Canceler: mg2) (Slaves: 18)
  Channel 19: FXS Kewlstart (Default) (Echo Canceler: mg2) (Slaves: 19)
  Channel 20: FXS Kewlstart (Default) (Echo Canceler: mg2) (Slaves: 20)

  20 channels to configure.

  DAHDI_SPANCONFIG failed on span 1: Invalid argument (22)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create span for Wildcard TDM410P. Only one thing you should do is to configure channels the right way. Here is your minimal `/etc/dahdi/system.conf` for using this card:

```
loadzone=us
defaultzone=us    
fxsks=1
```

Maybe it is too late to answer this question, but here I am.